# French Railroad metric complete?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be any metric space and let $p\in X$ and let $d_p$ be the corresponding french railroad metric. That is, $d_p(x,y)=d(x,p)+d(p,y)$.

I'm supposed to show that $(X,d_p)$ is necessarily a complete metric space.
So any Cauchy sequence in $(X,d_p)$ had better converge to some $x\in X$.

Can someone help me go about showing that there cannot be a Cauchy sequence whose limit is not in $X$?

Comment: But $d_p$ isn't a metric - the axiom $d(x,x)=0$ is not satisfied. Are you sure you definition is right? (Maybe you explicitly want to set $d(x,x)=0$?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof completeness of $(X,d)$ given $d$ is French railway metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163655/proof-completeness-of-x-d-given-d-is-french-railway-metric)

Comment: Milo I believe the french railroad metric comes with the caveat that $d(x,x)=0$