# Completeness of French railroad metric space

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

The [French railroad metric](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrenchMetroMetric.html) on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined as $||x - y||$ is $x, y$ are on a line that goes through the origin, or otherwise as $||x|| + ||y||$.

Prove this forms a complete metric space.

*Note: This question is discussed [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163655/proof-completeness-of-x-d-given-d-is-french-railway-metric).  I am posting nonetheless because the proof there is debated (with 10 comments going back and forth), and I'd like help verifying what to me seems like a simple proof.*

**Proof:**
If $x$ and $y$ are on the same line through the origin, refer to them as *corail*.  *Corail* forms a partition of $\mathbb{R}^2 -$ the origin.

Let $\{S_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in this space.
If $S$ eventually restricts to a single line through the origin, the metric reduces to Euclidean metric on the real line, and is therefore complete.

Alternatively, if $S$ always has points $a, b$ not corail, $d(a,b) = ||a|| + ||b|| \geq max(||a||,||b||)$.  Since $S$ is Cauchy, $d(a,b) \to 0$, so $||a|| \to 0$ and $||b|| \to 0$.  A similar argument applies to any point $c$ other than the origin appearing in the sequence after $a$ and $b$: $c$ is either not corail with $a$ or not corail with $b$.  Thus, all points in $S$ tend to an Euclidean norm of $0$, and so $S$ clearly converges to the origin.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: I’d say it’s correct, but perhaps you need to show us how you argue “… for any point $c$ in the sequence”. You need to extend your result to the case that infinitely many points are and aren’t on lines through the origin

Comment: @FShrike Edited accordingly. Does that do the job? (I introduced and defined a term _corail_ to clarify the exposition.)

Comment: It looks good to me! $\|c\|$ is forced arbitrarily small in either case